# Why does EF return 0 results for a search for NULL

Tags: entity-framework-6

My database has a bit column which is nullable, called `IsPerpetual`.

I'm trying to retrieve a collection where this column is `null`. I am failing to do so

My code is very simple

```
var dc = new DalCf.Entities(ProgramState.ConnectionString);
var results = dc.Main.Where(a => a.IsPerpetual == null);
var testForKnownEntryWithNull = dc.Main.Single(a => a.Id == 24589);
var isNull = testForKnownEntryWithNull.IsPerpetual == null;  //isNull is true ?!?
```

The value `results` returns a collection with 0 items.

The value `testForKnownEntryWithNull` has a property called `IsPerpetual` which is set to `null`

The value `isNull` is true.

Am I supposed to be querying EF 6 in a different way? I am totally bewildered with this.

I'm running this code in a unit test (MS Tests) in VS2019 on .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Can you try and see with this code: `var results = dc.Main.Where(a => !a.IsPerpetual.HasValue);`

Comment: Check the generated SQL (`results.ToString()`). If there is no `WHERE` clause (or has something like `WHERE 1=1`), then most likely the `IsPerpetual` property is marked as required (via attribute or fluent API).